# miner.start(1) is giving error as Failed to generate mapped ethash dataset epoch=1 err=”cannot allocate memory”

Tags: mining

I am facing an issue here when I start the miner process with miner.start(1). It gives me error as below. I tried to search for the solution but could not find any. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Intel i3 processor, 4 GB RAM and 4 GB Swap. I also tried to look for answers on this platform but didn't see any relevant solution.

```
    miner.start(1) 
    INFO [10-24|18:55:59] Updated mining threads threads=1 
    INFO [10-24|18:55:59] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000 
INFO [10-24|18:55:59] Starting mining operation null 
    INFO [10-24|18:55:59] Commit new mining work number=1 txs=1 uncles=0 elapsed=667.378µs 
    INFO [10-24|18:56:02] Generating ethash verification cache epoch=1 percentage=80 elapsed=3.010s 
    INFO [10-24|18:56:03] Generated ethash verification cache epoch=1 elapsed=3.687s 
    ERROR[10-24|18:56:03] Failed to generate mapped ethash dataset epoch=1 err=”cannot allocate memory” runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 2164260864-byte block (119799808 in use) fatal error: out of memory
```

Comment: Even I had issues with miner.start(). Though you can try to start geth with `--mine` flag.

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar issue.
The problem was i was running the `32bit` version on a `64bit` system.
Kindly confirm that you are using the correct version for your system`(32bit or 64bit)`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure this was the problem? I am running on Ubuntu 32bit on a 64bit machine. If you say so, let me try re-installing the OS and install the ether setup again.

Comment: It was the problem for me.  
I was running the 32bit Geth on a Windows 10 64bit system.  
I can not say for sure the same problem happens on Ubuntu, though.